# error:Incomplete or corrupt PNG file in using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want to add 2 images in my `pdf` when i click "create-pdf" icon.
First image is a canvas that convert to image and it correctly work.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("jade-schematic-diagram");
img = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
img.id="pic2";
doc = new jsPDF({
    unit:'px', 
    format:'a4'
});
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20,400,150);
```

This section of my code got this error:

> Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

```
var srcpath;
var element = $(".plot-waveforms"); // global variable
var imgageData = new Image();
imgageData.id = "pic";

html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        srcpath = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
});
imgageData.src=srcpath;
doc.addImage(imgageData , 'PNG',  20, 20,400,150);
```

I was added these script in my html head tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zlib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="png.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="png_support.js"></script>
```

Please help me. I searched a lot but i don't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onrendered` is an async function, isn't it? https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/470

So you have to place `srcpath` inside `onrendered`

```
html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        srcpath = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        imgageData.src=srcpath;
        doc.addImage(imgageData , 'PNG',  20, 20,400,150);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The image has not finished loading when you send it to **jsPDF**. So in order to ensure that the image has finished loading before adding it to the document, Add this to your code :

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage .src = 'https://www.myserver.com/somepath/myImage.png';
myImage .onload = function(){
doc.addImage(myImage , 'png', 5, 5, 40, 10);
doc.save('myPDF.pdf');
};
```